# how to deploy custom UIPlugin.war with the ovirt engine?

Tags: servlets, jboss, rhel, kvm

I have been working on a project where i need to make an UI Plugin which gets added in the ovirt.
front end of UI plugin has been added by following the url:http://www.ovirt.org/Features/UIPlugins
but i am not sure where should i put my backend code which has been written using java servlet so that the requests, defined in my UI plugin, can be handled by my servlet.